# No sound from Debian beside beeps

Tags: debian, audio

I bought Lenovo ideapad 500S and installed Debian 8. It's a fresh install, and no other OS is on this computer.

I am having difficult on enabling the audio and days of googling to hunt any hint resulted no any good.

I'll write down some outputs on the commands below. Any help appreciated.

Audio device on `lspci -v`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3828
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 142
    Memory at d4320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at d4310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

`alsamixer` with the sound card selected. No muted, no improper level on volumes.

```
┌───────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.0.28 ──────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA Intel PCH                                  F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Intel ID 2809                                  F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Master [dB gain: -20.25]                       Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                              │
│     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐                       ┌──┐      │
│     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │                       │  │      │
│     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     └──┘     └──┘     ┌──┐   Enabled    └──┘      │
│     │OO│     │OO│     │OO│                       │MM│                        │
│     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘                       └──┘                        │
│      41    100<>100 100<>100 100<>100   0<>0                       0<>0      │
│  < Master >Headphon Speaker    PCM    Mic Boos  S/PDIF  Auto-Mut Internal    │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.0.28 ──────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA Intel PCH                                  F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Intel ID 2809                                  F2:  System information │
│ View: F3: Playback  F4:[Capture] F5: All             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Mic Boost [dB gain: 0.00, 0.00]                Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                              │
│                  ┌──┐               ┌──┐               ┌──┐                  │
│                  │  │               │  │               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │  │               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │  │               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │  │               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │  │               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │  │               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │  │               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │▒▒│               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │▒▒│               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │▒▒│               │  │                  │
│                  │  │               │▒▒│               │  │                  │
│                  └──┘              L└──┘R              └──┘                  │
│                                   CAPTURE                                    │
│                  0<>0              39<>39              0<>0                  │
│          <    Mic Boost     >     Capture       Internal Mic Boost           │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

`id dinir` (every debian site tell me to check if I have privilege on audio and stopped there from being more helpful)

`uid=1000(dinir) gid=1000(dinir) groups=1000(dinir),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev),110(lpadmin),113(scanner),119(bluetooth)`

`patcl list sinks`

```
Sink #0
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
              balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 113847 usec, configured 371519 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ID 236 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ID 236 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd4320000 irq 142"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d70"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel ID 2809"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0236,17aa381e,00100002 HDA:80862809,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900)
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

`pasuspender -- speaker-test -c 2 -D hw:0`
This is a speaker test and I am supposed to hear pink noise. After running it while I get some error messages.

```
speaker-test 1.0.28

Playback device is hw:0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 16384
Period size range from 32 to 8192
Using max buffer size 16384
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 4096
was set buffer_size = 16384
 0 - Front Left
Write error: -5,Input/output error
xrun_recovery failed: -5,Input/output error
Transfer failed: Input/output error
```

Comment: Assuming you've selected your card (and it looks like you have) I'd go to F5 (all) and see if anything looks down or off that shouldn't be. BTW, nice ASCII art. Did you do it yourself? I also suggest you fire up `pavucontrol`. It occasionally tells you something useful.

Comment: Oh, didn't expected a comment speaking about ASCII one. It's `alsamixer` default and I just copy-pasted it here. ·_· Anyway, F5 reveals few more and they're seems related to microphone ones. what should I look for? Mic Boost - set to 0. Capture - set to 39.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realise that the output was ASCII. Also, feel free to pop into the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you want. Debugging is usually easier in chat.

Comment: Post a revised picture? :-)

Comment: Added F4 one, since they can't be in a single screen and I know F4 ones are what not seen on F3 while being seen on F5.

Comment: I see something called "Auto-Mut" is enabled. I'm guessing that is "Mute". Try disabling it. Also, fire up `pavucontrol` and see if the display wiggles if you play stuff. http://www.tutonics.com/2012/10/fix-no-sound-turn-off-auto-mute-in.html

Comment: I heard that Auto-mute is the feature automatically muting the speaker when you put a headphone on the machine. Of course I tried disable the Auto-mute and got no change. pavucontrol shows wiggling bar when I play something.

Comment: Hmm, that suggests the software is working. Though I'm not sure about the Auto-mute thing.

Comment: Why did I see that comment about chat room now... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing linux kernel 4.4.0 solved this problem.

My device is Lenovo Ideapad 500S-14ISK,
and `uname -r -v` is `4.4.0-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.4-1~exp1 (2016-01-19)` now.

I'll write everything I remember to install the kernel below, so other people with the same device could help themselves.

1. **Add the experimental repository to your `sources.list`.**
   The kernel I installed is not a stable version for now, so I have to allow my package manager to search and install things on the repository, which holds the kernel.

   - Add `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ experimental main` to the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I used vim to do that, so `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` will help you do this.
2. **Prepare to install the kernel.**
   If you're familiar enough with Linux, you can skip this one. This is for beginners like me who often forget basic things.

   - Update your package list. Do `sudo apt-get update`.
   - If you want to see other available kernels you can do `apt-cache search linux-image-4.4`.
3. **Install the kernel.**
   I chose `linux-image-4.4.0-trunk-amd64` and it is working well on my computer, so you can try this if your computer model is the same.

   - `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-trunk-amd64`.
4. **Reboot.**
   If you are greeted with the familiar login screen, congrats! You're all set.
   Test if the audio is really working by doing `speaker-test` on terminal. It will make a pink noise, and you can stop it with Ctrl+Z.

I am using xfce, so the package manager alerted me that while installing the kernel it will remove `task-desktop`, `task-xfce-desktop`, `xserver-xorg-input-all`, and `xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse`. I was afraid of it because when I installed kernel of version 4.3.0 I couldn't get back to the xfce interface. But since the installation went successful, it should be nothing to worry about.